# How do you negate an annotated field in django?

Tags: python, django

I have an annotated queryset in which I am annotating the sum of numbers.  However, I want the result to be the negative of that sum.  I can't seem to do it like this:

`Model.objects.all().annotate(total=-Sum('qty'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 2.1, negation was added as a [feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/).
This works in current versions:

`Model.objects.all().annotate(total=-Sum('qty'))`

In older versions, we can use F objects like this:

`Model.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum(F('qty')*-1))`